# Not able to open DTSX package

Tags: ssis, package

I was able to open the below dtsx package till yesterday on the production server. Today when i tried opening with Business Intelligence Development Studio i am getting the below error

Error Message :

Failed to load XML from package file "E:\Integrated Packages\FlowVision\Flow-Vision-ASN-ASP-Export\Flow-Vision-ASN-ASP-Export\FlowVisionASPASNExport.dtsx" due to error 0xC00CE508 "An invalid character was found in text content. Line 2, Column 2".  This happens when loading a package and the file cannot be opened or loaded correctly into an XML document. This can be the result of either providing an incorrect file name to the LoadPackage method or the XML file specified having an incorrect format.
 (Microsoft Visual Studio)

I google the above error message all were saying that it is corrupted file , and i need to redo the DTSX package . Can you guys help if you have any alternative to the solution.

Below is the first 5 Lines as requested :

```
h0
```

:   X0
:   ˆ@:    Ø2
:    ¸2
:   œ2
:   x2
:   X2
:   82
:    2
:   ü1
:   Ü1
:   Ð1
:      ¸1
:
   ˜1
:   „1
:   d1
:
   P1
:   41
:   $1
:   1
:   ø0
:   ä0
:   Ì0
:   °0
:   ˆ0
:   h0
:   X0
:   ˆ@:    Ø2
:    ¸2
:   œ2
:   x2
:   X2
:   82
:    2
:   ü1
:   Ü1
:   Ð1
:      ¸1
:
   ˜1
:   „1
:   d1
:
   P1
:   41
:   $1
:   1
:   ø0
:   ä0
:   Ì0
:   °0
:   ˆ0
:   h0
:   X0
:   ˆ@:    Ø2
:    ¸2
:   œ2
:   x2
:   X2
:   82
:    2
:   ü1
:   Ü1
:   Ð1
:      ¸1
:
   ˜1
:   „1
:   d1
:
   P1
:   41
:   $1
:   1
:   ø0
:   ä0
:   Ì0
:   °0
:   ˆ0
:   h0
:   X0
:   ˆ@:    Ø2
:    ¸2
:   œ2
:   x2
:   X2
:   82
:    2
:   ü1
:   Ü1
:   Ð1
:      ¸1
:
   ˜1
:   „1
:   d1
:
   P1
:   41
:   $1
:   1
:   ø0
:   ä0
:   Ì0
:   °0
:   ˆ0
:   h0
:   X0
:   ˆ@:    Ø2
:    ¸2
:   œ2
:   x2
:   X2
:   82
:    2
:   ü1
:   Ü1
:   Ð1
:      ¸1
:
   ˜1
:   „1
:   d1
:
   P1
:   41
:   $1
:   1
:   ø0
:   ä0
:   Ì0
:   °0
:   ˆ0
:   h0
:   X0
:   ˆ@:    Ø2
:    ¸2
:   œ2
:   x2
:   X2
:   82
:    2
:   ü1
:   Ü1
:   Ð1
:      ¸1
:
   ˜1
:   „1
:   d1
:
   P1
:   41
:   $1
:   1
:   ø0
:   ä0
:   Ì0
:   °0
:   ˆ0
:   h0
:   X0
:   ˆ@:Ô    :    .PAVCWMIError@WMI@@ ˆ@:0ã:Ô    :    .?AV_com_error@@    ˆ@:Ô   :    .?AVbad_exception@std@@ ˆ@:u˜  s˜                    à?pow            €ÿ       €ÿÿÜ§×¹…fq±
@      ÿÿ
@÷6C˜ö•ý?      à?exp          ¡7:­::²::á8:             Àÿÿ5Âh!¢ÚÉÿ?      ð?

```
p?  ˆ?   _       

    î?      ðC      ð;      ð?      à?      ÿÿþôV:úV:ÿV:W:
```

W:W:W:W:"W:>W:CW:YW:^W:zW:ŠW:žW:®W:ÎW:ÓW:íW:òW:X:&X:>X:RX:rX:wX:‘X:–X:¶X:ÊX:âX:öX:Y:Y:5Y::Y:ZY:nY:†Y:šY:ºY:¿Y:ÙY:ÞY:þY:Z:*Z:>Z:^Z:cZ:}Z:‚Z:¢Z:¶Z:ÎZ:âZ:[:[:![:&[:F[:Z[:r[:        ð      øÿÿÿÿÿÿÿï              €           üÿÿ5      @   ÿ  €   ÿÿÿ             ”&         è,
:   ì,
:   Ü,
:   à,
:   €-
:   x-
:!   p-
:   Ô,
:
   Ì,
:   ¼,
:   h-
:   `-
:    ,
:   œ,
:    ˜,
:   ´,
:   ¬,
:   X-
:   ¤,
:   P-
:   H-
:   @-
:   8-
:   0-
:"   ,-
:#   (-
:$   $-
:%   -
:&   -
:       €D        € 0                   @         È@         ú@        @œ@        PÃ@        $ô@       €–˜@        ¼¾@     ¿ÉŽ4@   ¡íÌÎÂÓN@ ðžµp+¨­Åi@Ð]ý%åŽOëƒ@q–×•C)¯ž@ù¿ Dí‚¹@¿<Õ¦ÏÿIxÂÓ@oÆàŒé€ÉGº“¨A¼…kU'9÷pà|B¼ÝŽÞùûë~ªQC¡ævãÌò)/„&D(ªø®ãÅÄúDë§Ôó÷ëáJz•ÏEeÌÇ‘¦® ã£F
eu†uvÉHMXBä§“9;5¸²íSM§å]=Å];‹ž’Zÿ]¦ð¡ ÀT¥Œ7aÑý‹Z‹Ø%]‰ùÛgª•øó'¿¢È]Ý€nLÉ›— ŠR`Ä%u    ÍÌÍÌÌÌÌÌÌÌû?q=
×£p=
×£ø?Zd;ßO—nƒõ?ÃÓ,eâX·Ññ?Ð#„GG¬Å§î?@¦¶il¯½7†ë?3=¼BzåÕ”¿Öç?ÂýýÎa„wÌ«ä?/L[áMÄ¾”•æÉ?’ÄS;uDÍ¾š¯?Þgº”9E­±Ï”?$#Æâ¼º;1a‹z?aUYÁ~±S|»_?×î/¾’…ûD?$?¥é9¥'ê¨*?}¬¡ä¼d|FÐÝU>c{Ì#Twƒÿ‘=‘ú:zc%C1À¬ÊóL¬/HYb‰‚IUÊÆ oäH²]ïqÅDöÈ .%‚s}kC£EQhÖ’oî‘‡OoHµD•+òŸÕ‹Ð?¡¸ÞKÄN¥<ŽQû¸&5ã}+K‘oG¯wéï“ˆaý¸Ö6nžH©ï LÂÁOùžÔí;D@Cºãày©]—ü<ßá[M¯Ï¤›†Ñv®|‚á»ýòÚO¦ÖÈ;bÿýÊëêK%E²ý‘a9²:V£¼Ÿfó&Oƒ*”O†€+‹«uØêN‘økCÉ,pÎ‹    ÁPE¨Ê9yírIÕÞ7w"KE°ó¨}—yz†\¶Ùû@¸Ê;[©5|sv „ìK«ÍÆ@B=ÃþöSm+}ÈL£ÍáO$»U¹à™B•q8þC^ÂV‹£—‚1dOŸnÃÓqÎ£ƒzâFþµƒK’n‡ÊjzäB]‡à=£dLÉw•òœ¤Íî†ÿ/xÏ@µ¼îý¡[~Ý0`W©ª–€E”dž#‚¦t¢¯QŒ·×O›Žˆä(ýCœ
´>ugÚ¡A„ËV)ÃpPf‰Œ¹¬ýùK­h‹D@cžC o m p l e t e     4
:    ô3
:   Ø3
:   ´3
:   3
:   h3
:   D3
:    3
:   ø2
:   S O F T W A R E \ M i c r o s o f t \ A c t i v e   S e t u p \ I n s t a l l I n f o   S O F T W A R E \ M i c r o s o f t \ W B E M \ C I M O M   W M I S e t u p     4
:    ô3
:   Ø3
:   ´3
:   3
:   h3
:   D3
:    3
:   ø2
:   Ø2
:    ¸2
:   œ2
:   x2
:   X2
:   82
:    2
:   ü1
:   Ü1
:   Ð1
:      ¸1
:
   ˜1
:   „1
:   d1
:
   P1
:   41
:   $1
:   1
:   ø0
:   ä0
:   Ì0
:   °0
:   ˆ0
:   h0
:   X0
:   ôI
:á
:ˆÇ:CÈ:        üP:üP:ž°
:J
:á
:ˆÇ:hÈ:        üP:üP:ž°
:J
:á
:ˆÇ:È:        üP:üP:ž°
:$J
:á
:ˆÇ:²È:        üP:üP:ž°
:                                        4
:    ô3
:   Ø3
:   ´3
:   3
:   h3
:   D3
:    3
:   ø2
:   Ø2
:    ¸2
:   œ2
:   x2
:   X2
:   82
:    2
:   ü1
:   Ü1
:   Ð1
:      ¸1
:
   ˜1
:   „1
:   d1
:
   P1
:   41
:   $1
:   1
:   ø0
:   ä0
:   Ì0
:   °0
:   ˆ0
:   h0
:   X0
:   4
:    ô3
:   Ø3
:   ´3
:   3
:   h3
:   D3
:    3
:   ø2
:   Ø2
:    ¸2
:   œ2
:   x2
:   X2
:   82
:    2
:   ü1
:   Ü1
:   Ð1
:      ¸1
:
   ˜1
:   „1
:   d1
:
   P1
:   41
:   $1
:   1
:   ø0
:   ä0
:   Ì0
:   °0
:   ˆ0
:   h0
:   X0
:   4
:    ô3
:   Ø3
:   ´3
:   3
:   h3
:   D3
:    3
:   ø2
:   Ø2
:    ¸2
:   œ2
:   x2
:   X2
:   82
:    2
:   ü1
:   Ü1
:   Ð1
:      ¸1
:
   ˜1
:   „1
:   d1
:
   P1
:   41
:   $1
:   1
:   ø0
:   ä0
:   Ì0
:   °0
:   ˆ0
:   h0
:   X0
:   4
:    ô3
:   Ø3
:   ´3
:   3
:   h3
:   D3
:    3
:   ø2
:   Ø2
:    ¸2
:   œ2
:   x2
:   X2
:   82
:    2
:

Comment: Use a text editor, notepad works, and open the .dtsx file. Copy the first 5 lines and then edit your question, paste the values in there and then click the Format button `{}`

Comment: Well, that's not what I expected... My assumptions were that 1) you had a version mismatch 2) a merge based VCS had left markers in there for conflicts 3) anything else, really. Instead, this looks exceptionally wrong. This isn't Encrypted, at least using the native SSIS. The fact that it has registry gunk in there and all that binary data, that package is flat out corrupt. Some process has destroyed that package beyond repair. I hope for your sake that this has been properly version controlled and it's a simple matter of getting the latest version.